# How to reverse POD status and PGI status?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Can anyone suggest function module to reverse POD status and PGI status?

I used `WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE_2` to update POD status and PGI from `A` or `B` to `C`, but how to reverse it?

Is it possible to reverse POD status from `C` to `A` just like a VLPOD and reverse PGI status from `C` to `A` just like a VL09.

This code updates POD status but I don't know how to reverse it

```
*** updating PGI status ***

ls_vbkok-wabuc = 'X'.
ls_vbkok-wadat_ist = sy-datum.
ls_vbkok-wauhr = sy-uzeit.
ls_vbkok-wadat = plandate.
ls_vbkok-kzwad = 'X'.

CLEAR: ls_vbkok-kzpod, ls_vbkok-podat, ls_vbkok-potim.

CALL FUNCTION 'WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE_2'
  EXPORTING
    vbkok_wa = ls_vbkok
    synchron = 'X'
    commit = 'X'
    delivery = ls_likp-vbeln
    update_picking = 'X'
  TABLES
    prot = lt_prot.

*** updating POD status ***

ls_vbkok-kzpod = 'D'.
ls_vbkok-podat = sy-datum.
ls_vbkok-potim = sy-uzeit.

CALL FUNCTION 'WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE_2'
  EXPORTING
    vbkok_wa = ls_vbkok
    synchron = 'X'
* NO_MESSAGES_UPDATE_1 = ' '
    commit = 'X'
    delivery = ls_likp-vbeln
* update_picking = 'X' "test stock
* nicht_sperren_1 = 'Y'
  TABLES
    vbpok_tab = lt_vbpok
    prot = lt_prot.

CLEAR: lt_vbpok, ls_vbpok, lt_prot, ls_likp.
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had an issue where I used the module function `WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE_2` and I had to reverse the delivery to status 'A' for my tests.

To reverse the status I executed transaction VL09.

After I read your issue I checked the code of that transaction, which is `RVV50L09`, and I found the module function `WS_REVERSE_GOODS_ISSUE`.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check `POD_STATUS_MAINTAIN` subroutine in `FV50XFPD` include.

It uses the following FM for reverting the POD status:

```
lips-kzpod = 'B'.

CALL FUNCTION 'LIPS_STATUS_MAINTAIN'
  EXPORTING
    f_likp   = likp
    f_posnr  = lips-posnr
    land1_we = kuwev-land1
  TABLES
    fxlips   = xlips
    fxvbapf  = xvbapf
    fxvbup   = xvbup
    fyvbup   = yvbup
    fxvbfa   = xvbfa.
```

Regarding PGI, ask the separate question.

Comment: Execute me sir, Can you show an example ?